# How to make Python choose between two options?

Tags: python, random

So, I've been writing a code in Python lately and it's been working perfectly until I wanted to have Python choose between two different outcomes.
The part of the code that doesn't seem to work looks like this:

```
line = ( (random.choice(str_a) + \
          random.choice(str_b) + \ 
          random.choice(str_c) + \
          random.choice(str_d) + \
          random.choice(str_e) + \
          random.choice(str_f)) or \
         ((str_g) + (random.choice(str_h)) )
```

`str_a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`are all lists that contain several words.
Now I want Python to randomly choose between either the combination of `a-f` OR the combination of `f,g`.
For some reason I do not get any errors, but Python just keeps choosing for the first option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because `a or b` always return `a` if `a` is true.

Comment: You are doing an or - it is always going to choose the first option.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
if random.choice((True, False)):
    line = random.choice(str_a) + random.choice(str_b) + random.choice(str_c) + random.choice(str_d) + random.choice(str_e) + random.choice(str_f)
else:
    line = str_g + random.choice(str_h)
```

This randomly gives you either one of each of the elements in `str_a`, `str_b`, `str_c`, `str_d`, `str_e`, `str_f` or it gives you `str_g + random.choice(str_h)`.

Comment: Or perhaps `''.join(random_choice(s) for s in (str_a, str_b, str_c, str_d, str_e, str_f))`. Depending on the types, of course, I'm assuming `str_a` etc are strings. For numbers use `sum`, and for unpredictable types `reduce(operator.add, ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use choice again?

```
line = random.choice([random.choice(str_a) + random.choice(str_b) + random.choice(str_c) + random.choice(str_d) + random.choice(str_e) + random.choice(str_f)), (str_g) + (random.choice(str_h)])
```

Comment: Oh dear. It was unreadable to begin with, now even more so. `"Simple is better than complex"`, you know. One-liners aren't that great.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, shortened, looks like

```
line = (expr1 or expr2)
```

The `or` operator picks the first expression that is truthy, which always is `expr1` in your case.

You probably wanted to write something like:

```
line = random.choice([expr1, expr2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`line = (random.choice(str_a) + random.choice(str_b) + random.choice(str_c) + random.choice(str_d) + random.choice(str_e) + random.choice(str_f)) if random.randint(0,1)>0 else (str_g) + (random.choice(str_h))`

Answer (score 0):

`or` in Python **does not** mean "choose randomly": `A or B` means "return `A` if `A` is truthy otherwise `B`". The first part of the expression is always truthy (as expected, because it seems to be a nonempty string) so you always get it.

If you have two values, say `A` and `B` then you can choose one of them randomly by using `random.choice((A, B))`. So you just have to define `A` and `B` before that:

```
A = (random.choice(str_a) + random.choice(str_b) + ...)
B = (str_g) + (random.choice(str_h))
line = random.choice((A, B))
```